# What is wrong with this loop in my Django view/template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I hate to ask here but I am stumped and so were the guys in irc.

The template does not display the contents of the list I am trying to display.

{{ bet }} alone also displays no values. What am I missing?

Template:

```
{% for bet in bets %}
<tr>
    <td><div>{{ bet.game_num }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ bet.home_team }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ bet.home_odds }}</div></td>
    <td><div id="home-odds-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
    <td><div>{{ bet.visiting_team }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ bet.visiting_odds }}</div></td>
    <td><div id="visiting-odds-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
    <td><div>{{ bet.tie_odds }}</div></td>
    <td><div id="tie-odds-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

View:

```
def choose_bets(request):
    # Should be a post to get to this page
    num_games = int(request.POST['games']) + 1

    # Fill BetData with teams and odds
    bets = []
    for x in range(1, num_games):
        try:
            league_id = int(request.POST[str(x) + '-league'])
            game_num = int(request.POST[str(x) + '-game_num'])
            home_team = request.POST[str(x) + '-home_team']
            visiting_team = request.POST[str(x) + '-visiting_team']
            home_odds = float(request.POST[str(x) + '-home_odds'])
            visiting_odds = float(request.POST[str(x) + '-visiting_odds'])
            tie_odds = float(request.POST[str(x) + '-tie_odds'])
            skip_game = False

        except ValueError:
            league_id,game_num,home_odds,visiting_odds,tie_odds = 0,0,0,0,0 # bad fix
            home_team,visiting_team = '',''
            skip_game = True    # Do not include entry in calculation

        finally:
            bets.append([game_num, league_id, home_team, visiting_team, home_odds, visiting_odds, tie_odds, skip_game])

    return render_to_response('choose_bets.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Context of bet variable:

'bets': [[1, 5, u'', u'', 1.0, 1.0, 3.0], [2, 4, u'', u'', 2.0, 2.0, 43555.0], [3, 3, u'', u'', 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template is referring to named fields in `bet`, but you passed in an array.

Either change your `append` in `choose_bets` like this:

```
bets.append(dict(game_num=game_num, league_id=league_id, home_team=home_team, visiting_team=visiting_team, home_odds=home_odds, visiting_odds=visiting_odds, tie_odds=tie_odds, skip_game=skip_game))
```

So you now have a dict with keys you can reference as-is from your template.

Or... change the template to use the array you are passing in.  For example instead of:

```
<td><div>{{ bet.game_num }}</div></td>
```

Use:

```
<td><div>{{ bet.0 }}</div></td>
```

Comment: Max, I owe you one. Thanks for spotting that for me.

Comment: Nice answer Max - code will show up better if you indent it 4 spaces (when adding or editing select your code and hit Ctrl-K, or select it and click the 0101 button, or just indent it 4 spaces manually). Inline code can be made to look like code using backticks (`). I've edited this post for you. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Ah hah! Fantastic - thanks for the edit and pointers.  I meant to familiarize myself with the markup but was in a rush of enthusiasm to get the post out.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [{% debug %}](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) tag. See if the context contains what you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try passing each variable through explicitly one by one and seeing at what point it stops working, rather than using locals